# Need a mail.php script for Form

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have a form but I need a mail.php for it but I am not a php expert is there anyone who can help me. Here is my form code

```
<form id="form1" id="form1" action="mail.php" method="POST">

    <label>Name
        <span class="small">Add your name</span>
    </label>
<input type="text" name="name">
    <label>Email
        <span class="small">Enter a Valid Email</span>
    </label>
<input type="text" name="email">
    <label>Phone
        <span class="small">Add a Phone Number</span>
    </label>
<input type="text" name="phone">
<label>DOB
        <span class="small">Date Of Birth</span>
    </label>
<input type="text" name="dob">

<br />
<br />

    <label>Salary
        <span class="small">Your annual Salary</span>
    </label>
 <input type="text" name="salary">

    <label>Loan Amount
        <span class="small">Loan</span>
    </label>
 <input type="text" name="loan">

     <label>Property Value
        <span class="small">value of property</span>
    </label>
 <input type="text" name="property">
    <label>City  
        <span class="small">City  </span>
    </label>
<input type="text" name="city">
<br />
<br />
<br />
    <label>Occupation
        <span class="small">Occupation</span>
    </label>
<select name="type" size="1">
<option value="update">Salaried</option>
<option value="change">Self Employment</option>
</select>
<br />
<br />
<br />


    <label>Message
        <span class="small">Type Your Message</span>
    </label>
<textarea name="message" rows="6" cols="25"></textarea><br />

    <button type="submit" value="Send" style="margin-top:15px;">Submit</button>
<div class="spacer"></div>

</form>
```

In this I need another check box in the end which is basically a disclaimer that user needs to check before submitting the form. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a "give me the code" kind of question and is not desired here. If you want help ask specific questions and show some effort on your part.

Answer (score 0):

You can read this article. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mail.asp It explains how you should do that.
Asimple mail function can be written as bellow.

```
<?php
$to      = 'name@domain.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: yourname@domain.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: yourname@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```